# Powershell Performance tuning for aggregation operation on big delimited files

Tags: powershell, file, delimited, group-object

I have a delimited file with 350 columns. The delimiter is `\034(Field separator)`.
I have to extract a particular column value and find out the count of each distinct value of that column in the file. If the count of distinct value is greater or equal to 2, I need to output it to a file.
The source file is 1GB. I have written the following command. It is very slow.

```
    Get-Content E:\Test\test.txt | Foreach {($_ -split '\034')[117]} | Group-Object -Property { $_ } | %{ if($_.Count -ge 2) { Select-Object -InputObject $_ -Property Name,Count} } | Export-csv -Path "E:\Test\test2.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Please help!

Comment: Did you try [Import-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-7.1).  Also, `Get-Content` is [known to be slow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47352340/9529842)

Comment: I'd also consider breaking apart the processing. With that many columns and the way it is being piped, it has to do an awful lot of in-memory processing before it can produce results. Really just the `Import-Csv` and export the single column into another file, perhaps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using a [`switch` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) to process the input file quickly (by PowerShell standards):

```
# Get an array of all the column values of interest.
$allColValues = switch -File E:\Test\test.txt {
  default {  # each input line
    # For better performance with *literal* separators, 
    # use the .Split() *method*.
    # Generally, however, use of the *regex*-based -split *operator* is preferable.
    $_.Split([char] 0x1c)[117] # hex 0x1c is octal 034
  }
}

# Group the column values, and only output those that occur at least 
# twice.
$allColValues | Group-Object -NoElement | Where-Object Count -ge 2 |
  Select-Object Name, Count | Export-Csv E:\Test\test2.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

<sup>Tip of the hat to [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) for suggesting the `-NoElement` switch, which streamlines the `Group-Object` call by only maintaining *abstract* group information; that is, only the grouping *criteria* (as reflected in `.Name`, not also the individual objects that make up the group (as normally reflected in `.Group`) are returned via the output objects.</sup>

---

As for **what you tried**:

- [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) with line-by-line streaming in the pipeline is *slow*, both *generally* (the object-by-object passing introduces overhead) and, *specifically*, because `Get-Content` decorates each line it outputs with ETS (Extended Type System) metadata.

  - [GitHub issue #7537](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7537) proposes adding a way to opt-out of this decoration.
  - At the expense of memory consumption and potentially additional work for line-splitting, the `-Raw` switch reads the *entire file* as a single, multi-line string, which is much faster.
- Passing `-Property { $_ }` to [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object) isn't necessary - just omit it. Without a `-Property` argument, the input objects are grouped *as a whole*.
- Chaining [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) and [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) - rather than filtering via an `if` statement in a [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) call combined with *multiple* `Select-Object` calls - is not only conceptually clearer, but performs better.

---

Comment: This is nice, `Group-Object` tho, in my experience, tends to be slower than a normal `foreach` loop with the needed logic inside.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, yes, `Group-Object` is slow; `-NoElement`, as suggested by Mathias, should help, but the best-performing solution here would be to maintain a hashtable that maps field values to their count as part of the `switch` statement, which is more work, however.