# Powershell script to remove quotes in file

Tags: powershell

I need help removing double quotes in the content of all the files in a directory. I can get it done one file at a time and its fast too not sure how to do it for all files without impacting performance. There are more than 600 files in the directory.

**PS script for one file:**

```
(gc C:\Temp\data.txt -En UTF8) | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace '"',''} | Out-File C:\Temp\data.txt -En UTF8
```

Trying with all the files in a folder using code below. But, its been too slow.

**PS script for all files:**

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Temp" -Filter *.txt | 
Foreach-Object {
    $content = Get-Content $_.FullName

    #filter and replace content to the original file
    $content | % {$_ -replace '"', ''} 

    #save content to the same file name
    $content | Out-File $File.BaseName -En UTF8
}
```

Comment: `Get-Content` is [known to be slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47349306/powershell-get-content-with-basic-manipulations-so-slow)

Comment: Are your files just text files or CSV files? If CSV, then simply removing all quotes is hazardous. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60681762/9898643)

Comment: Hi @Theo, they are all text files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming each input text file fits into memory as a whole (which is likely), you can **use

[`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content)'s `-Raw` switch** as follows, which greatly speeds up your operation:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Temp -Filter *.txt | 
  Foreach-Object {
    (Get-Content -Raw $_.FullName) -replace '"' |
      Set-Content -NoNewLine $File.BaseName -En UTF8
  }
```

Note:

- `-Raw` reads the entire contents of a file into memory as a *single, (typically) multi-line* string.
- Omitting the replacement operand of the `-replace` operator *implicitly* uses `''` (the empty string) as the replacement string.
- If the input already *is* text (strings), [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) performs better than [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) / `>`.
- `-NoNewLine` (PSv5+) ensures that `Set-Content` / `Out-File` don't blindly append a newline. (It actually also suppresses placing newlines *between* the (stringified) input objects, but in the case at hand there's only *one* input object).